# Create Regex to read line

Tags: c#

I am trying to create regex to read the following statement

`Finding all possible schedules that could run at Thu Jul 02 09:30:00 EST 2015 on monitor AAA-AAA_NameOf Place`.

**Done So far::**

```
 string name = @"^Finding all possible schedules that could run 
                ?<Listname>(\w{3}\-\w{3}\_)+"; //got kinda lost here 
 Regex reg = new Regex(name);
```

What do I want?

I want to get this  `AAA-AAA_NameOf Place` as an output and assign it in an list. As well as the date in the statement can be different every time.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: We need **rules** about how that value can appear.  Does it always have a dash in it?  Is the value before and after the dash always the same?  Does it always have an underscore?  Is that space actually in the there?   Is the value always at the end of the line?  Etc...

Comment: The value is always the same but character will be different of course. Just to make it more clear AAA-AAA_ (this format will always be there but can be different alphabet). Where as `Nameof Place` can have more or less character

Comment: ...and is the value after the underscore always from there to the end of the line?  Because if it has spaces like that then how can we know where the value ends?

Comment: @Idle_Mind it is the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
var data = "Finding all possible schedules that could run at Thu Jul 02 09:30:00 EST 2015 on monitor AAA-AAA_NameOf Place";
string namePattern = @"(?<=monitor\s).*$";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(data, namePattern).Value);
```

Refer here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion

Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry dude forget to mention the date will be different.

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol The regex pattern this sample uses has nothing to do with the date.  It's a positive look behind saying that the word "monitor " is right before what you're looking for.

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol: This produces your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
(.+? at )(?<Date>.+?)( on monitor )(?<NameOfPlace>.+)
```

It will product two named groups: `Date` and `NameOfPlace`.

Please note that it assumes the exactly same format.

Once you get the `Date` and `NameOfPlace`, you can assign them to List.

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/RAP15Royna)

[For how to get the values from regex matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Regex that looks for a character at the beginning of a word boundary that is repeated three times then followed by a dash, then that same character repeated three more times followed by an underscore, then followed by any number of characters after that at the end of the string:

```
        string input = "Finding all possible schedules that could run at Thu Jul 02 09:30:00 EST 2015 on monitor AAA-AAA_NameOf Place";
        string pattern = @"\b(.)\1\1-\1\1\1_.+\Z";
        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
```